# Help for having quadratic equation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I know that $X\sim N(6,2^2)$ and $P(X^2-6X\leq 0)$.
How do I convert to standart normal distribution?

Comment: Please show us where are you stuck and what have you tried.

Comment: I do for P(X<=0) and P(X<=6) then the answers are 0.9987 and 0.5

Answer (score 0):

With a bit trick, you have:
$$\mathbb P(X^2-6X<0)=\mathbb P(0<X<6)$$
from which you can use the CDF of standard normal distribution.